# Sound sometimes goes away

Tags: windows-7, audio

I'm using 64 bit Windows 7, Toshiba laptop. It's been working for years, nowadays the sound just suddenly goes silent. If I change the volume, nothing happens. As soon as I plug in and out a headphone, the sound comes back. My sound card is Conexant Audio.

Comment: sounds like something might be wrong with either a driver or the jack's hardware.  headphone jacks sometimes have physical switches in them that close a different circuit if headphones are present.  If that switch is failing, then your laptop might be trying to play sound over your headphones when they are not connected.  Or, it could be a driver issue, and cycling with the headphones could be getting the driver unstuck

Comment: to be precise: if im listening with headphones, it never goes away, only when without it

Comment: that makes sense; i'd lean towards a faulty jack at that point then, that's falsely reading that headphones are plugged in

Comment: I removed all sound drivers, reboot, still the same